# How to make Json.stringify ignore certain class memebers?

Tags: json, haxe

I'm using the latest Haxe and HaxeFlixel to make a simple game prototype.

I have the following class...

```
class GameData
{
    public var playerHealth: Int;
    public var playerScore: Int;    

    public var levelName: String;

    public function new(playerHealth: Int = 0, playerScore: Int = 0, levelName: String = "")
    {
        this.playerHealth = playerHealth;
        this.playerScore = playerScore;

        this.levelName = levelName;
    }
}
```

I convert it to JSON as follows...

```
Json.stringify(new GameData(64, 512, "Level 1"));
```

Is there's a way I can make it so the stringify ignores certain members?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`haxe.Json` has no mechanism to exclude fields, so I would recommend using a third-party library such as [json2object](https://github.com/elnabo/json2object/) that does. Here you can simply annotate fields that should be ignored with `@:jignored`:

```
@:jignored
public var levelName:String;
```

```
var data = new GameData(100, 10, "Level 1");
var json = new json2object.JsonWriter<GameData>().write(data);
trace(json); // {"playerHealth": 100,"playerScore": 10}
```

There are some possible workarounds that don't involve adding a library to your project, but they don't seem very nice:

- Don't serialize the object directly, but a structure that only includes the desired fields:

  ```
  var data = new GameData(100, 10, "Level 1");
  var json = Json.stringify({
      playerHealth: data.playerHealth,
      playerScore: data.playerScore
  });
  trace(json); // {"playerHealth":100,"playerScore":10}
  ```
- Remove the unwanted fields after serialization - this seems rather hacky as it involves a lot of unnecessary overhead due to an additional `Json.parse()` and `Json.stringify()` call:

  ```
  var json = Json.stringify(new GameData(100, 10, "Level 1"));
  var data:haxe.DynamicAccess<String> = Json.parse(json);
  data.remove("levelName");
  json = Json.stringify(data);
  trace(json); // {"playerHealth":100,"playerScore":10}
  ```

Comment: Didn't really think about the idea of serializing a structure that contains only the desired fields, very awesome thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your exact situation, it can be desirable to make a slightly modified version of standard library's JsonPrinter - for example, in GMEdit I allow JSON objects to have an `hxOrder: Array<String>` field, which, if provided, determines the field order for printing, and is initialized to a static array. You can make a similar scheme for field inclusion/exclusion.